# PyQt4 Give Focus to Widget as it is called by the MainWindow and set as CentralWidget?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, pyqt4, qt5

I want to give Focus to a QLineEdit as soon as it appears... in other cases (all Widgets within the same class) it was possible with `.setFocus()` - but here this doesn't work.
My candidates are `.activateWindow()`and `.raise_()`, but I couldn't figure it out how to use them.

edit: My goal is to be able to type into the QLineEdit directly from the keyboard without the need to hit the `tab` key or click with the mouse in advance.

Here an example of the relevant parts in question (functional):

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Quiz(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        edit = QLineEdit("Select & Focus")
        edit.selectAll()
        edit.setFocus()             # doesn't work - no effect at all

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(edit)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        startQuiz = QAction("Start Quiz", self)
        startQuiz.triggered.connect(self.startQuizQuestions)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        quizMenu = menubar.addMenu("&Quiz")
        quizMenu.addAction(startQuiz)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("xyz")
        self.show()

    def startQuizQuestions(self):
        newQuiz = Quiz()
        self.setCentralWidget(newQuiz)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you're seeing me terribly misusing Python or PyQt4... feel free to criticise, I want to learn.

edit: I found in the [PySide Docs](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html?highlight=setfocus#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.activateWindow) for `.activateWindow` this discouraging "comment": "On Windows, if you are calling this when the application is not currently the active one then it will not make it the active window." - But I mean it IS the active Window (=MainWindow) it is just an other Widget in the CentralWidget of the active Window. (?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works if you give the widget a parent.

Here is the init function of the widget with a new parent argument, used for the QWidget. Then the QWidget is used as parent for the label.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    edit = QLineEdit("Select & Focus", self)
    edit.selectAll()
    edit.setFocus()             # works now

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(edit)
    self.setLayout(vbox)
```

After that you have to pass the `MainWindow` as parent to the widget like this:

```
newQuiz = Quiz(self)
```